# Giving Date parameter to mongoose query as local time

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, mongoose, momentjs

On my Node.js project I need to give query Date parameter which should be startOf current hour in local time. for example, if current local time is 2019-11-13T16:34:43.000, I should give date parameter as 2019-11-13T16:00:00.000.

For the reason I can't figure out, query accepts date only and only with `New Date()` function. No `moment()` or nothing else. I'm creating the date with `moment()` and then update it's hour by `startOf('hour')` and  by `format` functions. The issue I live here is that, when I give this date to `New Date()` function inside query, `New Date()` function converts it to UTC time. I need my date in query to be executed as local time(Turkey Time - GMT+03:00).

```
const DriverPlan = analysisDB.collection('driverplans');
    const nowDate = moment().startOf('hour');
    console.log('nowDate: ', nowDate);
    console.log('Unformatted: ', nowDate.valueOf());
    const localDate = moment(nowDate).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS');
    console.log('localDate: ', localDate);
    const courierPlans = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      driverPlan.find({ startDateL: new Date(localDate) }).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(result);
      });
    });
```

and here is my console after the code block executed.

```
nowDate:  moment("2019-11-13T16:00:00.000")



Unformatted:  1573650000000


localDate:  2019-11-13T16:00:00.000
```

So when I pass this `localDate` variable (which is my local time) to `New Date()` function inside query, `Date` function converts it to UTC.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I assume that all your date are given in utc because the process is running on a utc timezone machine.

I would look at https://momentjs.com/timezone/
This is useful because it accounts for the day-light saving.

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

// Create a moment with the current date
const now = moment();

//Convert to wanted timezone
now.tz('Europe/Istanbul').startOf('hour').toDate()
```

I would suggest using `moment().toDate()` instead of `new Date()`.  This will ensure that you are using the same moment object.  Unfortunately, the date object will always display in the timezone of the process.

It is possible to set the timezone via an env variable
`process.env.TZ`.  This can be fragile depending on the usage.